# I want to customize the error text that is shown after validation

Tags: flutter, controller

I want to customize my error text for both input.isEmpty and multivalidator,and this my code down below.

```
                      TextInputField(
                     icon: FontAwesomeIcons.user,
                     hint: 'Nom et prénom',
                     inputType: TextInputType.name,
                    inputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                     validator: (input) => input.isEmpty
                         ? "veuillez saisir votre Nom et prénom"
                         : null,
                   ),
                  TextInputField(
                      icon: FontAwesomeIcons.envelope,
                       hint: 'Email',
                       inputType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                       inputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                       validator: MultiValidator([
                         RequiredValidator(
                             errorText: "Veuillez saisir une adresse mail"),
                         EmailValidator(
                            < errorText:
                                 "Veuillez saisir une adresse mail valid"),
                      ])),
```

Comment: Please format your code correctly.

Comment: I agree, this is a mess

Comment: done .sorry it was my first post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the decoration property:

```
 decoration: InputDecoration(
            errorStyle: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.red,
              fontSize: 14,
              fontStyle: FontStyle.italic
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: If this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.